# Eclipse JRE error ? How to fix it?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

The error is like this

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    abc     Unknown Java Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [OSGi/Minimum-1.2]' in project 'abc'   abc     Build path  Build Path Problem

I think it happens from Installed Jre's when I go there I see no Jres

Im also using Mac os x 10.10.1 yosemite

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Im also using Mac os x 10.10.1 yosemite

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it . Not a fix for juno but
I downloaded eclipse indigo And it detected Jres automatically .
Then for android I just add ADT to Indigo 
Thats it .